# How to specify completion handler with one function not return

Tags: ios, swift

So I was trying to use a code block like this:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
    self.delegate?.graphWasSelected(DisplayInformation.getReportGraphsForReportType(self.reportType)[indexPath.row])
}
```

protocol definition:

```
protocol GrapherPickerTableViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func graphWasSelected(graph : DisplayInformation.ReportGraph)
}
```

> Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type
>   '(BooleanLiteralConvertible, completion: () -> Void)'

So to my understanding, because it is the only statement in a completion block it is trying to return it? Is there a way to tell it not to? (I'm guessing this has something to do with the delegate being an optional?)

Right now I'm solving it by manually putting in a "return" statement after it, but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Comment: This is not directly relevant to your question, but there is absolutely no reason for you to be saying `[weak self]` here. Delete that, and refer to `self`, not `self!`.

Comment: I actually just took it out, was throwing some stuff in there seeing if it would help (always a reliable strategy). Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: In fact, the whole `[weak self] () -> Void in` is unnecessary.

Comment: How is the type of `delegate` declared? Is it a protocol? Please show it, and show the actual declaration for `callThisFunction`. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to show protocol declaration and actual function call

Comment: Another option is `_ = returnsValue()`, although I would go with the explicit return.

Comment: The `return` is a good solution. Or update to Xcode 6.3 beta; the version of Swift that it contains should solve this for you.

Comment: Ahh, I thought there might be a signifier to solve this. I may update to the beta. Thanks guys.

Comment: Well, instead of using the optional chain with `delegate?`, you could test explicitly whether `delegate` is nil and force-unwrap it if it is not: `if self.delegate != nil {self.delegate!.graphWasSelected(...)}` That way you avoid returning an `Optional<Void>` which is what you are doing now.

Comment: Of course, thanks matt. I knew I could go with that, just wasn't sure if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You cannot avoid the fact that your one-liner is being treated as the object of an implicit `return` and you are thus returning the wrong type (`Optional<Void>` instead of Void). You've been given three suggestions including your own, and I think they are all "elegant": make it a two-liner, or return the correct type. But the new version of Swift cuts you a break on this, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, I appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.